# Should C++ namespaces be wrapped in company namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11

In Java packages are generally prefixed with company (com.example.department.project....), is this commonly done in c++ as well?

To the point, if I'm developing a library, should I wrap the namespace in company name? Something like

```
namespace company {
    namespace project {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this commonly done in real world c++ practice? And even if it's not a common practice, when starting new C++11/14 greenfield project, is it a good idea to do so?

Comment: I have done this before, but it definitely isn't common, and I usually don't.  In my experience in industry even using a namespace at all isn't as common as it should be though :/

Comment: I edited a question little bit, added the "And even if it's not a common practice, when starting new C++11/14 greenfield project, is it a good idea to do so?" part, would you be so kind and comment on that?

Comment: I am so unsure about the answer that I'm not even going to have an opinion (yet), but I am curious to see what responses you get :)

Comment: C++ namespace should be some high-level title that wrap some classes and functions. it hsould reflect the area the objects/functions are dealing with. company name has nothing to do with it. also, namespace has the task of diffrentiating between few classes or variables with the same name but different functionality. think if your project needs this at first place